# Best way to update html after promise result

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, ionic2

I wonder to know the best way of binding result of a promise which is as an injection to html tag using angular 2(I use ionic 2)...
As you know the main problem with async coding is loosing reference to the current object. It seems I should pass current object as a prameter to Promise function generator. 
I searched internet for better solution but nothing I found! So is there any better approch?

> Ionic 2 itself use observation and subscribe to do async proccess. But the major problem is that for existing functions which are not observable it couldn't work!

My approch:

Injectable class:

```
export class PromiseComponent {
    doPromise = function (obj: any) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve2) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve2({ num: 3113, obj: obj });
            }, 5000);
        });
    }
}
```

Call on click:

```
  promiseVal = 0
  doMyPromise() {
    this.myPromise.doPromise(this).then(this.secondFunc);//UPDATED HERE
  }


//UPDATED HERE
  secondFunc = function (res) {
    this.promiseVal = res.num
  }
```

Html:

```
 <div>{{promiseVal}} </div>
 <button (click)="doMyPromise()">Do Promise</button>
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Do you want to update `promiseVal` but also keep the old value?

Comment: No. just updating promiseVal after TimeOut in html

Comment: Then what do you mean with reference stuff? Just assign the `res.num` to `promiseVal`. What's the problem?

Comment: @echonax . Because it has ERROR with this message: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'promiseVal' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'promiseVal' of undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to consume a promise inside your component:

```
promiseVal = 0
doMyPromise() {
  this.myPromise.doPromise().then((res) => {
    this.promiseVal = res.num
  });
}
```

And I don't know the reasoning behind your Service but it usually is like this (optional):

```
export class PromiseComponent {
    doPromise() { //This method will return a promise
        return new Promise(function (resolve2) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                resolve2({ num: 3113, obj: obj });
            }, 5000);
        });
    }
}
```

**After OP edited the post:**

You can change this:

```
doMyPromise() {
    this.myPromise.doPromise(this).then(this.secondFunc);//UPDATED HERE
}
```

to

```
doMyPromise() {
    this.myPromise.doPromise(this).then(this.secondFunc.bind(this));//UPDATED HERE
}
```

Comment: after calling then function, browser couldn't find `this ` in this.promiseVal. It seems lossing the reference to the current compnent. So if this work why error happen here?

Comment: @SiamakFerdos did you replace `doMyPromise` as I've written? If so, if `doMyPromise` is inside a component, `this` will refer to the component.

Comment: I recover where's the problem... I use a function in `then` which I define it before. When I put function directly into `then` it works. but for reducing the question I put that function definition to `then`. In this case it not works! I uapdated my question...

Comment: @SiamakFerdos I don't know why you are complicating things for yourself but check my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

> As you know the main problem with async coding is losing reference to the current object

That's not true, the arrow function does not bind its own `this` therefore you don't need to send `this` to `doPromise`

```
export class PromiseComponent {
  doPromise () {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      setTimeout(function () {
        resolve({ num: 3113 })
      }, 5000)
    })
  }
}

promiseVal = 0
doMyPromise() {
  this.myPromise.doPromise()
    .then(res => {
      this.promiseVal = res.num
    })
}
```

Comment: It has error :  ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot set property 'promiseVal' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot set property 'promiseVal' of undefined

Comment: Yes you right. My problem is happen when I put a function variable into `then` and when I put function directly in `then` no problem accur at all!!